# How do I center 2 divs next to each other with space between other div's that doesn't increase on window resize

Tags: css

I can't manage to center 2 `<div>`s of mine next to each other without the spaces between the divs growing or shrinking on window resize.

The problem is that I want the 2 divs to have 5px space between them (in the exact middle and a few px space to the outer sides also, but I can't get it to work.

When I set the width to 49% the space in the middle is increasing on window resize and when I set the width to 50% the 2 `<div>`s which are supposed to be next to each other go underneath each other on a lower windows size.

I basicly want the containers to have a minimum width but no maximum width, the containers grow or shrink on window resize BUT spaces between the containers should stay exactly as big as they are, all the time.

I'd be happy with a basic example how I can get this done:

http://gyazo.com/1c2f3c4a639580f46d16f7e65a52a46a

```
    .container{

    border-radius: 5px;

    background-color:#6F0098;

    box-sizing: border-box;

    width:49%;
    height:auto;

    min-width:700px;

    padding:3px;

    overflow:hidden;

    margin:auto;
}

.inner_container{

    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;

    background-color:#343434;

    box-sizing: border-box;

    width:100%;
    height:auto;

    box-sizing: border-box;

    padding:5px;

    overflow:hidden;

    color:#CCCCCD;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a simplified version of your markup? It's helpful for us to know where your divs are

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/drohwwza/?

Comment: Sadly I don't have any code left.. I'd be happy with some basic example how I can get this done:
http://gyazo.com/1c2f3c4a639580f46d16f7e65a52a46a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flexbox` solution is one of the alternatives to older approach.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks so much for every help. :)
Lot's of tears got saved. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is most likely going to have to do with...

```
margin-left:5px;
```

or

```
margin-right:5px;
```

You need to post your markup if you want more help than that.